# Error test failure when solving two coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

by `NDSolve`;
this is work until `y=6.22`

```
sol = NDSolve[{f'''[y] + f[y] f''[y] + 4 - (f'[y])^2 == 0, 
    g''[y] + 0.01*f[y] g'[y] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == -1, 
    f'[10] == 2, g[10] == 0}, {f, g}, {y, 0, 10}]
g[0] /. sol
```

after that I got this

> Error test failure at y == 6.0045645472974165`; unable to continue.

I need to increase the value ...is there  another way rather than ND-solve.

Comment: i cannot increase the max value here ..bvb's involving ode's

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX or regular math notation, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. It also helps to post working code (that is, the complete `NDSolve` command you used in this instance). You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ODE system can be solved using the option `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`, although the computation proceeds slowly.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{f'''[y] + f[y] f''[y] + 4 - (f'[y])^2 == 0, 
    g''[y] + 0.01*f[y] g'[y] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == -1, 
    f'[10] == 2, g[10] == 0}, {f[y], g[y]}, {y, 0, 10}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> 10^6];
Plot[sol, {y, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {y, "f,g"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

[image]

**Addendum: Faster, More Robust Solution**

Particular characteristics of the ODE system permit solving it more simply than  with the general approach given above.  Specifically, `g[y]` does not appear in either of the ODEs, although its derivatives do.  Consequently, the boundary condition, `g[10] == 0` can be satisfied merely by solving the system with `g[0] == 0` satisfied instead of `g[10] == 0`, and then subtracting from the solution the value of `g[10]` as just calculated to force `g[10] == 0`.  To proceed, solve the system parametrically with

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'''[y] + f[y]*f''[y] + 4 - (f'[y])^2 == 0, f[0] == 0, 
    f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == fpp, g''[y] + coef*f[y]* g'[y] == 0, g[0] == 0, g'[0] == -1}, 
    {f[y], g[y] - g[10], f'[10]}, {y, 0, 10}, {fpp, coef}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

A coupling coefficient, `coef`, has been introduced to simplify obtaining solutions for various coupling coefficients, as requested by the OP in a comment below.  (`WorkingPrecision -> 30` is needed only for values of `coef` of order `4` or larger.)  Note also that `ParametricNDSolve` is instructed to return `g[y] - g[10]` as explained just above, and also `f'[10]`.  The desired solution is obtained by varying `fpp` with `FindRoot` until `f'[10] == 2`.

First, plot `f'[10]` as a function of `fpp`.

```
Plot[Last[s[fpp0, 1/100]] - 2, {fpp0, 3.36, 3.5}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {fpp, "f'[10]"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

[image]

Perhaps surprisingly, there are two solutions for `f'[10]` == 2, at `fpp` of about `3.37` and `3.49`.  The first of these yields the solution

```
fpp0 /. FindRoot[Last[s[fpp0, 1/100]] == 2., {fpp0, 3.37}, Evaluated -> False]
(* 3.37136 *)
Plot[Evaluate@Most@s[%, 1/100], {y, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {y, "f,g"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

producing a plot identical to that above, as expected.  The new solution is

```
fpp0 /. FindRoot[Last[s[fpp0, 1/100]] == 2., {fpp0, 3.49}, Evaluated -> False]
(* 3.48628 *)
Plot[Evaluate@Most@s[%, 1/100], {y, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {y, "f,g"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

[image]

I have obtain solutions for `coef` as large as `7`, shown below, without difficulty.  Still larger values require a higher `WorkingPrecision`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you so much ...your help will change many things related to my success

Comment: but still cannot give me the value of g[0]/.sol

Comment: Happy to help.  Use `Last@sol /. y -> 0`, which yields `8.95717`.

Comment: in this code i faced a lot pf problem when I replace 0.01 by number greater than 5 or numbers like 0.72 ... can i solve this system by another built in function ....sorry for  keep asking ..

Comment: @OneTwo  A modification of my earlier answer will handle the larger coupling constant.  I shall add it in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

We can simplify the procedure since the f-equation can be solved totaly independent of the g-function. Thanks to the inspiration by @bbgodfrey.

First solve the f-equation with initial conditions. (I found parameters i1 and i2 with FindRoot since shooting method did not work with my version 8.0 in that case.)

```
fsol[i_?NumericQ] := 
   f /. First@
   NDSolve[{f'''[y] + f[y] f''[y] + 4 - (f'[y])^2 == 0, f[0] == 0, 
 f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == i}, f, {y, 0, 10}]

i1 = i /. FindRoot[Derivative[1][fsol[i]][10] == 2, {i, 3}]

(*   3.37136   *)

i2 = i /. FindRoot[Derivative[1][fsol[i]][10] == 2, {i, 5}]

(*   3.48628   *)

Plot[Evaluate[{fsol[i1][y], fsol[i2][y]}], {y, 0, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now use the found fsol[y] interpolating function for the second g-equation together with the cuppling constant coef all for the both found i1 and i2.

```
gsol[i_?NumericQ, coef_?NumericQ] := 
   g /. First@
   NDSolve[{g''[y] + coef*fsol[i][y]* g'[y] == 0, g'[0] == -1, 
 g[10] == 0}, g, {y, 0, 10}]

gsol[i1, .01]

Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate[{gsol[i1, coef][y], gsol[i2, coef][y]}], {y, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, PlotRange -> All], {{coef, .01}, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Appendix to the OP's comment  `..that to see the influence of changing the parameter( Coeff of f(y)g'(y)) from 0.01 to 0.02 .......4 5 10 100 1000 and so on . so i need numerical result for g(0) f''(0) with different value of the parameter ..` .

(Needs higher workingPrecision for fsol and rationalizing:)

```
fsol[i_?NumericQ] := 
  f /. First@
 NDSolve[{f'''[y] + f[y] f''[y] + 4 - (f'[y])^2 == 0, f[0] == 0, 
  f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == Rationalize[i, 0]}, f, {y, 0, 10}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 25]


(vals = Table[{coef, 
 Evaluate[{gsol[i1, coef][0]*Derivative[2][fsol[i1]][0], 
   gsol[i2, coef][0]*Derivative[2][fsol[i2]][0]}]}, {coef, {0.01, 
  0.02, .05, .1, .2, .5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 100, 1000}}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{gsol[i1, coef][0]*Derivative[2][fsol[i1]][0], 
  gsol[i2, coef][0]*Derivative[2][fsol[i2]][0]}], {coef, 1/100, 
  1000}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help.... the aim from solving this system of equations ..that to see the influence of changing the parameter( Coeff of f(y)g'(y)) from 0.01 to 0.02 .......4 5 10 100 1000 and so on . so i need numerical result for g(0) f''(0) with different value of the parameter ....what ever you help a lot and will be selfish to ask more about this ....again thank you so much

Comment: I made an edit to take this into account.

Comment: again and again thank to all ....

Comment: but why this value Derivative[2][fsol[i2]][0] dose not  change as the parameter change ...and by the way i need the values for g(0),..f''(0)..separately

Comment: Think a little bit!

Comment: I sorry to keep asking am just a beginner ... at this time am just deal with built in functions what ever ..thank you so much ...I will try my best to understand all the above ..and convert it on the way I want ...thank you so much